# How to find the parent of a Maven transitive dependency

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc, log4j

I am building a Java (web) application with Maven and Eclipse.

When I look inside my `.war` file I can see the following logging libraries there:

```
log4j-1.2.14.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
```

I did not declared these libraries in my `pom.xml`, so they probably are transitive dependencies (i.e. dependencies of my dependencies).

How can I find out which of my dependencies depend on these libraries?

I tried to use the `mvn dependency:tree` plugin, but it does not show any of these `.jar`s.

In Eclipse, the `Java Resources > Libraries > Maven Dependencies` node does not show them either. Though, curiously, it shows other transitive dependencies of my project.

Comment: With eclipse, you should try to edit the pom. There's a special tab named "Dependencies". From there, you should see your parent dependencies + you could consider choosing what version of dependency you want to keep.

Comment: @Olivier @Evgeniy The the `Dependency Hierarchy` tab really has a dependency tree. But my `.jar`s are not there.

Comment: Post your POM file. Seems unlikely that Maven would populate a war file with a jar that does not appear in the dependency tree

Comment: I downloaded the two poms and made a build, and those jars do not show up in WEB-INF/lib in my case. So the dependencies could only have come from demo-lib.You could try to go to demo-web, run mvn dependency:tree and post the full dependency tree here and post the demo-lib pom, maybe some plugin is copying jars around, it's strange to have a module demo-lib with no dependencies at all.

Comment: @jHadesDev Thank you for your help. I will try to build my project on another computer. I found the tool that I was looking for.
I will open another question if I still have problems with dependencies in my POMs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to rely on maven only you may want to take a closer look on the dependency plugin, here are two examples:

`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` will display more detailed information - especially for example if a artifact will be omitted for conflicting with another artifacts version (e.g. convergence issue). It will also display you the hirachy with all the transitive dependencies.

To have a specific artefact analyzed (to for example find who delivers a specific transitive dependency) you can specify like so:

`mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.my.group.id:my-artefact-id:jar:1.0.1 -Dverbose`

(Where you obviously need to adjust the artefact, packaging type and version according to your needs)

Answer (score 4):

Open `pom.xml` in Eclipse and go to `Dependency Hierarchy` tab

Comment: Evgeniy, thank you for the idea. The `Dependency Hierarchy` tab really has a dependency tree. But my `.jar`s are not there.

Comment: Go into the Filter on the top right of the Dependency Hierarchy Windows and type in your artifact. During typing this will filter out the rest and show which artifact's are in the tree of them.

Comment: @khmarbaise the filter returns empty set. They are not there.

Comment: Are you trying to do that in your parent of your project?

Comment: This answer was closest to the correct solution. My transitive dependencies were not shown on the `Dependency Hierarchy` tab probably because they were
declared as `<optional>true</optional>` in their dependent's POMs. However, a double-click on a dependency opens its own `pom.xml` in
which you can see all `optional` dependencies. I still do not understand why some of these dependencies ended up in my `.war`,
but I can make it a topic for another question.

Answer (score 1):

![enter image description here][1]

It should show you the dependency tree in the Dependency Hierarchy tab. Evgeniy Dorofeev is right. 
Something similar to the screenshot attached

you would probably have to expand all.

**EDIT:** Refined the answer. 
Thats a little weird. But here is what i found.

If you go to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17

it will show you which dependencies are used and which does the jar file depend on.

The springframework dependency for web-mvc 3.2.4 would download the spring-core and the spring-core dependency uses log4j.

Comment: Hrishikesh, I am confident that they are not in this dependency tree.

Comment: i see, that is weird. Found out the reason for the dependency download through mvnrepository.com. Updated the answer

Comment: Hrishikesh, thank you. Your answer clarifies things. I updated my question. But still, I'd like to know an easier way to build my dependency tree than web search :)

Comment: I completely agree. The reason why i did the web search is because your pom was relatively smaller and i was wanting to find out what might be the cause. :)